# Setup CLion with ROS

Tags: ros, ide, clion, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have some troubles setting up CLion to work properly with ROS (kinteic).

CLion does not recognize my workspace properly thus the IDEs features do not work.

**How to setup CLion with ROS?**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/284786/setup-clion-with-ros/) by [CoffeeKangaroo](https://answers.ros.org/users/34027/coffeekangaroo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 65 on 2018-03-08

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

## JetBrains now offers their own instructions on how to setup ROS with CLion: [see here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/2018.3/ros-setup-tutorial.html)

---

CLion is a nice tool but for me it did not work out of the box as claimed sometimes. This should be a beginner (primary targeting students) friendly guide on how to use CLion with ROS.

### How to setup CLion with ROS (kinetic) [as simple as possible]:

*Note: this how to is tested on Ubuntu 16.04 with CLion 2017.1.3 and 2017.3.2, the process might be different with other versions.

I recommend to check if `catkin_make` runs properly in your workspace before you start with this guide. In this way you know CLion is the problem, not ROS.*

- Start CLion from the terminal to ensure everything is sourced properly. You can alternatively edit the `.desktop` file, see below).
- Click "Import Project from Sources"
- Select the `<your workspace path>/src` folder in your workspace
- Click "Open Project" - code editor should open
- Go to "File" - "Settings" - "Build, Execution, Deployment" - "CMake"
- Set the generation Path to `<your workspace path>/build` and apply
- Finally you should right-click on your top level `CMakeList.txt` file in CLion and select "Reload CMake Project"

CLion should work properly now.

**Always start CLion from terminal unless you changed the `.desktop` file!**

### Rename Project/Workspace:

At the restart of CLion the Project will be shown at the recent projects with the name "src".
The project/workspace can be renamed by renaming the `<your workspace path>/src/.idea/src.iml` to `<your workspace name>.iml` and changing the path to it in `<your workspace path>/src/.idea/modules.xml` and by creating a file `<your workspace path>/src/.idea/.name` (containging only a name for the project).

```
cd src/.idea
NEW_NAME=my_workspace
mv src.iml $NEW_NAME.iml
sed -i -e "s/src/$NEW_NAME/g" modules.xml 
printf "$NEW_NAME" >  .name
```

If CLion shows you the info "This file does not belong to any project target" right-click the `includes` folder an click "Mark Directory as" and select "Project Sources and Headers".

### Setup debugging:

- Go to "Run" - "Edit Configurations" and click the add button
- Set a name
- Select a "Target" and the according "Executable", keep the "Configuration" on Debug and apply

Now you can run and debug from the terminal. This does not work with `.launch` files

### Highlighting in `.launch` files:

CLion does not recognize `.launch` files as XML files by default.

- Go to "File" - "Settings" - "Editor" - "File Types"
- Search for XML in the recognized files list
- add `*.launch`

.launch files should now have proper highlighting and autocomplete

### Change the `.desktop` file:

- Go to `<your home folder>/.local/share/applications`
- change the according line the `.desktop` file for your CLion version to:

  `Exec=bash -i -c "<clion installation path>/bin/clion.sh" %f`

### Note:

CLion is free for students:  [students click here](https://www.jetbrains.com/student/)

---

Originally posted by [CoffeeKangaroo](https://answers.ros.org/users/34027/coffeekangaroo/) with karma: 65 on 2018-03-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [0xd1ma](https://answers.ros.org/users/27403/0xd1ma/) on 2018-12-19**:
Set the generation Path to:

```
<your workspace path>/build
```

for me, it works if:

```
<your workspace path>/build/<name of your node>
```

and it is necessary to clear catkin workspace and rebuild pkg from the command line

**Comment by [0xd1ma](https://answers.ros.org/users/27403/0xd1ma/) on 2018-12-19**:
and for debug, you must select "Executable":

```
<your workspace path>/devel/lib/<name of your node>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

by the way . If you don't wanna build all projects in directory `<your workspace path>/src` , you can add `-DCATKIN_WHITELIST_PACKAGES="your_pkg1_name;your_pkg2_name"` in `CMake options` that located in
`File->Settings->Build,Execution,Deployment->CMake`

---

Originally posted by [pengjiawei](https://answers.ros.org/users/31790/pengjiawei/) with karma: 138 on 2018-03-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1